# List all images in a directory not listing contents

Tags: php, image, readdir, closedir

I am using the following to list all of the jpg images in a directory, for some reason its not working though, I think some of my 's and .s may be in the wrong place, I think I have confused myself a bit :-S .

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('images/photobanner')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'jpg')
    {
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'<img src="'.$file.'.'"/>'</a></li>';
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>

<P>List of files:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the concatenating lins as below.

```
    $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$file.'"/></a></li>';
```

and befor starting loop declare `$thelist`, that it is available in the scope

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$thelist` is only known in your while-loop.

If you change your beginning to this, it should work:

```
<?php
$thelist = "";
if ($handle = opendir('images/photobanner')) {
```

The technical term for your problem is 'scope'.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `glob()` is best for you, and you have some extra `'`:

```
$thelist = '';
foreach (glob("images/photobanner/*.jpg") as $file) {
    $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$file.'"/></a></li>';
}
echo $thelist;
```